# Better Solution for DVD Menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, hta

I'm currently reworking a setup for a software DVD for Windows. I use a hta file since javascript is enabled in there by default. (The setup must work by autorun without any settings or installation of 3rd party runtime environments)

The last major version of it is from 2012 where I introduced bootstrap 2 which works very nice with some fixes for IE. Now I wanted to migrate to bootstrap 3, but it seems like it doesn't support the IE-viewer used by hta. (8 In my case) 
A html setup is very comfortable since I have experience with bootstrap, jquery etc.

Is there a better way to do so? I'm looking for something like hta (preferably) without IE (or a way to run with a modern rendering engine. I can't tell the customers that they should install a newer IE than the OEM version preinstalled) and without need to install another runtime environment.

Comment: Can you post your HTA code ?

Comment: What are you interested in exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with IE10, HTC's are [considered deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801216(v=vs.85).aspx) and should be replaced by more modern solutions.

You may be able to keep things working for a bit longer by adding an `x-ua-compatible` header (as shown in the above link).  In the long run, however, you'll need to find a different way to create your menu.

One possibility is to use [Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs) to create an app hosting either a [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182879.aspx#WebView) or [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx) control, one that loads your HTML content and displays it.

Another possibility is to use a different development environment to create an actual app to be used as your DVD menu.

In any event, HTC's have a very short shelf life moving forward.  The IE Team is [on record](https://twitter.com/JustRogDigiTec/status/564523749903302657) as saying they will not be supported in Spartan (the new version of IE being developed for Windows 10).

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers!

I already tought about the solution with a webview, but the client needs .NET runtime for this (imho) what is unacceptable.

I just found node webkit (https://speakerdeck.com/zcbenz/node-webkit-app-runtime-based-on-chromium-and-node-dot-js) that builds (I already use nodebob) all the stuff needed for html together with chromium which is very nice and a perfect replacement for my current hta. (more precisely I ship now all dependencies and also have only one browser to test) There are various packages through node.js to access the file system and start setups, too. I just migrated to bootstrap 3 yet and opened a test file with module 'opener'. Seems to be very comfortable and widely used.